# Constructor vs. new

Tags: c++, class, pointers, new-operator, typedef

I just wanted to confirm the difference here, take this as an example:

```
class Gate
{
   public:
           Gate(); //Constructor
           void some_fun();
   private:
           int one, two;
           ptr p1;
           Gate* next;
};
typedef Gate* ptr;

Gate::Gate()
{
  one = 0;
  two = 0;
}

void Gate::some_fun()
{
  p1 = new Gate;
  p1 = p1->next;
  p1 = new Gate();
}
```

In my example, I have created 2 new nodes of "Gate" and the only difference between them is that the first node does not have the variables "one and two" initialized, while the second one does.

Comment: There is no difference between `new T` and `new T()` for a class which has the default constructor explicitly defined like yours. That constructor will be executed in either case.

Comment: @Josh, Did you actually run this code an check the results?

Comment: Your `some_func()` leaks one `Gate` object.

Comment: @jrok, two actually, since there are no deletes anywhere. But yes, no way to access the first allocated `Gate` in `some_fun`.

Comment: It is explained at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C++ has two classes of types: PODs and non-PODs (“POD” stands for “plain old data” … a somewhat misleading hint).

For non-PODs, there is *no* difference between `new T` and `new T()`. The difference only affects PODs, for which `new T` doesn’t initialise the memory, whereas `new T()` will default-initialise it.

[So what are PODs](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/intrinsic-types.html#faq-26.7)? All built-in C++ types (`int`, `bool` …) are.

Furthermore, certain user-defined types are as well. [Their exact definition is somewhat complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special) but for most purposes it’s enough to say that a POD cannot have a custom constructor (as well as certain other functions) and all its data members must themselves be PODs. For more details, refer to the linked FAQ entry.

Since your class isn’t a POD, both operations are identical.

Comment: I am not sure (nor want to actually test, I am feeling lazy here) that POD is the good division in this case: `struct x { int a; std::string b; }`, I *think* for that non-POD type `new x` and `new x()` make a difference.

Comment: That test does not verify my concern. I was sure that the `std::string` would be initialized, but I was not sure whether the POD member in the struct would be initialized or not. I have written a [test](http://ideone.com/Xg3bW) that verifies that it is uninitialized in either case --the behavior is different than the that of object with automatic duration (functions `f` and `g`) which is what confused me.

Comment: @David Huh. This test shows that even for `new test()` the POD member of the class is uninitialised and I’m having a really hard time believing that right now. Furthermore, I also don’t understand the results of the stack-allocated object in `x`. Why does it print the filler bytes from your `operator new` after the first call?

Comment: I will answer the simple one, then think about the other... The simple one is the `new`, the standard determines that `new` for non-POD types (it explicitly says non-POD, which I did not think it did) will call the default constructor, in this case *implicitly defined*. The implicitly defined default constructor is equivalent to `test::test(){}` (no initialization list, no body). Absence of the initialization list means that members with constructors will have it called, but for POD types does nothing. The behavior is expected (knowing that `new T` is *default-initailization*)

Comment: ... On the other issue (*why is the filler shown in the first pass of the `f()` function?*), the answer is also simple conceptually: because that is the value that is in the stack over which the variable is placed. There are different parts of the code that use that *filling*, the dynamically allocated memory (that cannot be in the stack) but also `operator<<` (and the internal workings of it). I hoped to have a simple example to change the value for something else, but failed. At any rate if you reorder the calls to `f()` and `g()` you will get the last value of the internal variable in `g`

Comment: @David Well, `operator <<` only contains a single `0xba`. I suspect (but haven’t checked) that the function might be inlined and the loop  unrolled, causing `0xbabababa` to be put on the stack. Otherwise I still can’t explain the result.

Comment: I cannot completely explain the result (I have made a couple of tests without success) but `operator<<` is called with the `x` member that is an `int`, not a single char. There is a single char in `operator new` but that is not the case of `operator<<`

Comment: @David Yes, I meant `operator new`.